# Why do we need the CakePHP HTML Link helper?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am teaching myself the CakePHP framework. I see that CakePHP comes with a bunch of helpers, for example, the HTML helper. In the docs, I see that you can write

```
echo $this->Html->link('Enter', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

and it will display

```
<a href="/pages/home" class="button" target="_blank">Enter</a>
```

What exactly has this helper gained us? Both seem to be equally easy to write.

Comment: From the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html): "_The role of the HtmlHelper in CakePHP is to make HTML-related options easier, faster, and more resilient to change. Using this helper will enable your application to be more light on its feet, and more flexible on where it is placed in relation to the root of a domain._" Implementation is a choice. You can use the method that best suits your situation.

Comment: HTML Helper in CakePHP to make HTML easier and faster.  It also give you a standard way of code to practice by providing well-formatted elements. These can cache views in Cakephp for improve performance.

Comment: The most obvious benefit is that the URL will be correct even if the app isn't installed to document root (e.g. if you install to `foo/` it generates `<a href="/foo/pages/home" ...>`)

Comment: Why was that totally valid question closed? The cite from the book does not really explain all the background why should use it and it is not the first time I see people asking for that reason, at least in IRC.

Answer (score 2):

In the comments George already mentioned the excerpt from the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html):

> The role of the HtmlHelper in CakePHP is to make HTML-related options
>   easier, faster, and more resilient to change. Using this helper will
>   enable your application to be more light on its feet, and more
>   flexible on where it is placed in relation to the root of a domain.

But this is missing another very important point: If you want [to use routing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) you won't be able to use it without using the array notation of the HtmlHelper.

Your code here

```
echo $this->Html->link('Enter', '/pages/home', array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

Would not work with routing. *You always should use the array notation* for links on your site. So instead you want:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Enter', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home'), array('class' => 'button', 'target' => '_blank'));
```

Another solid reason to use the helper is that links to your app are generated properly when the app is not set up to work in the root of the host.

Answer (score 0):

The `link` method in the HTML helper is handy to avoid hard-coding URLs in your views. Having…

```
<a href="/shop_products/view/1">Product Name</a>
```

…Is no good if you then add a custom route in your routes file to handle the above as something like `/t-shirts/blue-t-shirt`. Whereas if you use the array syntax…

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Product Name', array(
    'controller' => 'shop_products',
    'action' => 'view',
    $product['ShopProduct']['id']
)); ?>
```

…Then the HTML route will use reverse routing and drop in the URL format as required. No more updating link URLs across your application’s views.